# Converting PDF to PNG with transparent background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, imagemagick, transparency, rmagick

We have a Ruby on Rails application that needs to convert a PDF into a PNG with a transparent background. We're using rmagick 2.13.1. On our development machines the following code works exactly how we want it.

```
pages = Magick::Image.from_blob(book.to_pdf.render){ self.density = 300 }
page = pages[0]

image_file = Tempfile.new(['preview_image', '.png'])
image_file.binmode
image_file.write( page.to_blob { |opt| opt.format = "PNG" } )
```

We thens save the image_file and all is peachy. When we deployed to a review server on Heroku, though, the generated image has a white background. It turns out that Heroku's cedar stack is using imagemagick ImageMagick 6.5.7-8 2010-12-02 where we're using ImageMagick 6.7.5-7 2012-05-08 on our development machines.

I've scoured the net for older posts that might apply to the older version to try and figure out how to generate the transparent PNGs. It's surely supported, but, so far I haven't been able to figure out the right combination of settings.

To verify that it wasn't the PDF generation that was the problem, I downloaded a PDF generated on Heroku and successfully converted it using the above code (slightly modified to read the file in instead of generate it) to a transparent PNG.

Some of the things I've tried in various combinations are:

- `page.matte = true`
- `page.format = "PNG32"`
- `page.background_color = "none"`
- `page.transparent_color = "white"`
- `page.transparent("white")`

So, the question is "is this possible?". If so, which settings do I need to set on the image before writing it out?

I'm also investigating including a compiled binary of a more up to date Imagemagick on Heroku.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should no longer be an issue, as Heroku has ImageMagick versions 6.7-6.9 on their various stacks.