# Point imagick to location other than /usr/bin

Tags: php, heroku, imagemagick, imagick, pecl

I'm trying to compile the imagick extension for Heroku, but I need it to look in the `/app/bin` folder for ImageMagick rather than the `/usr/bin/` folder. I've used as much google-fu as I have, but I can't figure out how to build the imagick.so extension and have it point to a different folder.

From PHP, if I do `shell_exec("which convert")` it echoes the `/app/bin` version, but when I do `Imagick::getVersion()` it points to the `/usr/bin/` version. This makes me think it's an issue in the extension.

I haven't ever had to `make` my own extension from source, so that could definitely be part of the reason. Anything you could do to point me in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: Actually I should have asked earlier "but I need it to look in the /app/bin folder for ImageMagick rather than the /usr/bin/ folder." What makes you think you need to do this? i.e. what error are seeing?

Comment: It's a bug related to an old version of Imagick (which is what is on Heroku) that causes transparent backgrounds to be rendered as black sometimes. (See [topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178251/converting-pdf-to-png-with-transparent-background))

Comment: So you're compiling Imagick but it's picking up the wrong Image Magick version? And also - "just call make with no parameters, scp it to my machine" are you compiling imagick locally then copying it to the sever?

Comment: Yeah, sortof. I'm compiling imagick on a Heroku worker (created by running `heroku run bash`) so that it's the exact same as my web server. I then scp it off the machine that it was compiled on so that I can include it with my project. (Heroku has an ephemeral file system, so I have to include it in my project or the imagick.so file will get blown away.)

Comment: Ok - what problem are you facing? i.e. what isn't working?

Comment: @Danack Like I said above, I need to update Imagemagick because of a transparency bug. And the problem with Imagick is I can't get it to use my `/app/bin` version as opposed to the `/usr/bin` version (which is a read only folder). Thanks for all of your help so far, btw

Comment: @Danack No more ideas?

Comment: So what happens when you set the --libdir to be what you want it to be?

Answer (score 0):

Try with a `php.ini` file in the webroot, with the following contents:

```
extension_dir="/app/bin"
extension=imagick.so
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Dbugger. PHP actually picks up the Imagick extension just fine, but the Imagick is using the `usr/bin` version of Imagemagick instead of the `app/bin` version installed using [this](https://github.com/aarondfrancis/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick/blob/master/support/package_imagemagick) buildpack.

Answer (score 0):

You may have the wrong end of the stick. You don't compile the Imagick extension against the Image Magick executables but against the Image Magick libraries. i.e. if you're installing Image Magick through a package manager, you should be installing "ImageMagick-devel" not "ImageMagick"

You can then set the directory that Imagick should look for the Image Magick libraries for with the setting:

```
./configure --libdir=/usr/lib64 --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config
```

Or similar depending on where the libraries are installed, and then call make.

However if you're already compiling Imagick you might as well as also compile Image Magick from source.

*Edit*

If I was standing behind you, this would probably be solvable in 5 minutes. I suggest:

1) Find where the Imagick libraries actually are on your system - in particular find the libMagickWand-6.Q16.so file.

2) Make sure you're copying the Image Magick libraries that you want to use to the live server as well as the Imagick library, unless you're statically compiling it (which you probably aren't).

3) Rename the lib that you don't want it to be compiled against. See if compiling Imagick picks the right version up then.

4) Debug the ./configure script for Imagick - you can print stuff out like `AC_MSG_RESULT(libs before $DEBUG_LIBS)` as I had to do for one issue:  https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/issues/8 and ensure it's picking the right version up when compiling.

5) Raise an issue at https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/ and get the Imagick guy to have a look.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I guess I assumed that that the Imagick extension just talked to whatever executables were installed on the system. I'm using this [buildpack](https://github.com/aarondfrancis/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick/blob/master/support/package_imagemagick) to build Imagemagick on the heroku dyno, and then I buld the Imagick extension after that. How should it be done?

Comment: @AaronFrancis How you are building Image Magick should be fine. Can you post how you're building the Imagick extension?

Comment: I followed [this article](http://www.amido.co.uk/chris-gray/compiling-php-extensions-like-mongo-and-memcache-on-heroku/) but just call `make` with no parameters, scp it to my machine and then put it in my app folder and add a php.ini

Comment: @AaronFrancis Can you answer the question from the comment on your question - aka what problem are you actually having?